# Does one consider "vs." or "versus" when alphabetizing?

Tags: word-choice, alphabet

I work at a game store, and my manager insists that "versus" is to be considered when alphabetizing, and is not in the same league as "a, as, the, and, of, or," and the like.

Although I do deem it more important a word than those other smaller ones, I don't think it should be considered when alphabetizing.

What's the right way?

Comment: Whatever the correct reasoning... do it the boss's way. Not everything your boss says should be done, but for this... yes.

Comment: Corollary: If considering "vs." when alphabetizing, should it be expanded?  In other words, should "Foo vs. Bar" be sorted before or after "Foo Village"?

Answer (score 5):

Well, as far as I know, the general rule when alphabetizing is that all words are considered, except articles.

*Versus* isn't an article, so I think it should be considered.

Comment: Usher recently released an EP called 'Versus'. Definitely should be considered when alphabetising there!

Comment: @Karl Otherwise, the question becomes whether Usher’s EP comes before or after Sigur Rós’ album _( )_.

Comment: It's a good job we're working by album and not having to discuss where to put the artist formerly known as Prince!